# STM32F10X timer

Tags: arm, stm32, interrupt, cortex-m

I have a problem regarding the timer-interrupt with my stm32f10 controller.
When I enable the counter of the timer the status register is set to 
0x1F because the following flags are set: UIF, CC1IF, CC2IF, CC3IF, CC4IF

Here is what i did:

```
#include <Compiler.h>
#include <Debug.h>
#include <STM32F10xxx.h>

#include <Reset.h>
#include "Example.h"
#include <HW_TIM.h>
#include <HW_NVIC.h>
#include <HW_RCC.h>
#include <RegBit.h>

unsigned volatile int sr =0;

static void SetBASEPRI(WORD const basepriVal) {
  register WORD basepriReg __asm("basepri");

    basepriReg = basepriVal;
}

static void SetCONTROL(WORD const controlVal) {
  register WORD controlReg __asm("control");

    controlReg = controlVal;
}

static void MainInit(void) {
 STM32F10xxx_Config();
 SetBASEPRI(0U);

 PeripheryEnable(RCC_TIM2);

 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, DIER, UIE);

 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, DIER, CC1IE);
 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, DIER, CC2IE);
 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, DIER, CC3IE);
 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, DIER, CC4IE);

 InterruptEnable(NVIC_TIM2);

 SetCONTROL(1U);
}

void timInit(void){

 TIM2.PSC = 0x0024;
 TIM2.ARR = 0xFFFF;

 TIM2.CCR[0] = 0x00FF; 
 TIM2.CCR[1] = 0x0A00; 
 TIM2.CCR[2] = 0x0F00; 
 TIM2.CCR[3] = 0xF000;

 SET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, CR1, CEN);

}

__declspec(noreturn) int main() {

  MainInit();

  timInit();

  while(1);
}

void IRQ_TIM2(void){
 //Delet IFs in SR
 //trying to clear SR by reading the register
 sr = TIM2.SR;
 sr= GET_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM,2,SR,UIF);

 //trying to clear SR by resetting the single bits
 RES_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, SR, CC1IF);
 RES_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, SR, CC2IF);
 RES_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, SR, CC3IF);
 RES_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, SR, CC4IF);
 RES_RBINDEX_REG_BIT(TIM, 2, SR, UIF);

 //trying to clear SR bei assigning 0 to SR
 TIM2.SR=0;

}

void IRQ_SysTick(void){
}

void IRQ_HrdFault(void) {   for ( ;; ) DEBUG_BREAK(1); }
void IRQ_UsgFault(void) {   for ( ;; ) DEBUG_BREAK(1); }
void IRQ_BusFault(void) {   for ( ;; ) DEBUG_BREAK(1); }
void IRQ_MemFault(void) {   for ( ;; ) DEBUG_BREAK(1); }
void IRQ_NMI(void)      {   for ( ;; ) DEBUG_BREAK(1); }
```

As I said, the problem is that all the flags are set when the Counter-Enable-Bit(CEN) is set. And I can't delete them in the subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late answer, but I faced today a similar problem I think this could help other people. First I doubt that the problem was that flags UIF, CC1IF, CC2IF, CC3IF, CC4IF are set or not set. If you check the Reference Manual on page 403 is written that those flags are set by the hardware, so when you reset them the hardware (which is running even when you are debugging) will set them automatically and you won't even notice the result. If you want to see the flags cleared with debugger I recommend to disable the timer and then perform some operations. Also it is a recommended style to check the source of the interrupt in the IRQ:

```
//comment the next line before release
#define DEBUG    
void IRQ_TIM2(void){
 //disable the timer for debug purpose
 #ifdef DEBUG
    TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;
 #endif
 //trying to clear SR by reading the register
 if (TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET) {

    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update); //clearing UIF
 } 
 if(TIM_GetITStatus(TIM2, TIM_IT_CC1) != RESET) {
    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update); //clearing CCIF
 } 
 //etc...
 //enable the timer
 #ifdef DEBUG
   TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
 #endif
}
```